# How to set DataGrid line color in DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, gridlines

How can I set a different grid line color for some rows in DataGrid through DataTrigger?

I tried this:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding in_stock, Converter={conv:LessThan 4}}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

But the grid lines are all the same, default color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to hide the grid line at each separate row but I bypassed it by removing all horizontal grid lines through `GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"` and creating one-pixel bottom border for each DataGridCell where it is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this method

```
 <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="HighLightCell" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding In_stock}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="3"
      ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridPersonList}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataGridPerson}"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource HighLightCell}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"
                  Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="*" >

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                  Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>


</Grid>
```

Comment: This only changes the row-background color, I need to change the color of a grid-line (which I think is BorderBrush property, but replacing Background with BorderBrush isn't working).

Comment: Edited the answer